# How to filter the specific packages in dependency with gradle?

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I need to include only certain classes from a dependency, to optimize my Jar.

For example:

If i want exclude all module of **spring-security-config** i write this code:

```
 configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module: 'spring-security-config'
 }
```

But what if I need only spring-security-config.http.* and exclude the other packages in the dependency?

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eriaz.png)

ShadowJar does something similar with its minification, however the jar doesn't work in aws lambda.

https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/minimizing/